# C# SaveFileDialog come out warning when using "System" user to running the WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

When using a WinForm to click a button. and call save filDialog will come out
"C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH7J9.jpg

The challancing is this software must be runing in the "System" user.
But I using the SaveFileDialog for saving a file. will comes out the message like "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop".

I guess the problem is that when I using "system" user, the default user profile is no exist and counld no find the "Destop" floder path.
Because it will not have the "user profile" @ "system" user.

This error comes out at I click the button, this application try to init the SaveFileDialog and also try genarate the icon shortcut on the left hand side so cause the error.
The dropdownbox also have the save problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hy3S.jpg

Could any one know how to remove the icon shourt cut at the left hand side and the dropdown box icon also have the same problem.

```
    using (var dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
         
            dialog.DefaultExt = "txt";
            dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            dialog.Title = "test";                
            dialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
            dialog.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
            try
            {                   
                DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(this);
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)                                       
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

            }
        }
```

I just using very very very simple code.

ps. I am using C#.net 4.0 , vs2010 running at win2008r2 and win 7

Thanks all !!!

Comment: why are you running a desktop app as "System" ?

Comment: Because this app is the testing tools for the services. To testing the system and network environment if i using the "Services" could it login to other M$ server.

Comment: why do i have the -1 rating .... >.<

Comment: "why do i" - if I had to guess: because you aren't showing *any* code, so people are having to guess at your scenario

Comment: Marc's comment gets to the real problem here: by running a desktop app as "System", you're causing yourself more problems than you're solving. Why do you need "System" rather than using (for example) an Administrator account? Specifically, what code do you think needs to run as "System"?

Comment: My boss said what to have a diagnoses tools to simulating the " Windows service" and  export the error. Windows service must be using system account

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the InitialDirectory property of the SaveFileDialog

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\yourDirectory";
```

You can also use this method to check if the my documents directory exists on disk.

```
Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
```

Comment: I tried can't ........-__- it will come out warning then go to "c:\\yourDirectory"; ......

Comment: @ChrisWong what kind of warning?

Comment: you can see my link at my first post 
same as this error
http://i.stack.imgur.com/wH7J9.jpg